# c++ tables of unions and structures

Tags: c++, structure, unions

I was told to write a program, that creates a union and structure, then creates two-element arrays of unions and structures and fills their fields. I have created a union and a structure, but how to fill their fields in arrays ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

union complex;

union complex{
      int i1;
      long double ld1;
      } u;

struct Person {
    char* name;
    int age;
    bool sex;
    void show(){
    printf("name %s, age %2.0d, sex %1d\n",
        name , age, sex);        
    };
} person;

int main(void)
{ 

    Person *o = new Person[2];
    complex *un = new complex[2];

    un[0]->i1=i;  

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried un[0]->i1=i; but it's not the proper way to do this.

Comment: You don't need to use new to create an array.

Answer (score 5):

`un` is an array of `complex`, not an array of pointers to `complex`. Therefore, `un[0]` is a `complex`, not a pointer to a `complex`.

Thus, you need:

```
un[0].i1 = i;
```

The global instance of type `complex` called `u` looks a bit pointless, and should probably be removed.

Comment: okay, and let's say I have it set un[0].i1 = 6; . How to print it ?

I was trying printf("i1 $2.0d", un[0].i1); but it prints me nothing.

Comment: it prints me properly values of structure fields but not union.

Comment: @newbDeveloper: It's best to edit the question, and copy-paste actual code. That looks like a formatting string error, you should use "%d" to print an int, there's no $ involved.